# from <module> import ... in __init__.py makes module name visible?

Tags: python, python-import

Take the following code example:

File `package1/__init__.py`:

```
from moduleB import foo
print moduleB.__name__
```

File `package1/moduleB.py`:

```
def foo(): pass
```

Then from the current directory:

```
>>> import package1
package1.moduleB
```

This code works in CPython. What surprises me about it is that the `from ... import` in `__init__.py` statement makes the `moduleB` name **visible**. According to [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement), this should not be the case:

> The from form does not bind the module name

Could someone please explain why CPython works that way? Is there any documentation describing this in detail?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any `import moduleB` before that?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. That's the complete files on which the situation can be reproduced.

Comment: I tried and it works on Python2.7 but not on Python3.2 ...

Comment: @JBernardo Use `from .moduleB import foo` to get the same effect under Python 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation misled you as it is written to describe the more common case of importing a module from outside of the parent package containing it.

For example, using "from example import submodule" in my own code, where "example" is some third party library completely unconnected to my own code, does not bind the name "example".  It does still import *both* the example/__init__.py and example/submodule.py modules, create two module objects, and assign example.submodule to the second module object.

But, "from..import" of names from a submodule must set the submodule attribute on the parent package object.  Consider if it didn't:

1. package/__init__.py executes when package is imported.
2. That __init__ does "from submodule import name".
3. At some point later, other completely different code does "import package.submodule".

At step 3, either sys.modules["package.submodule"] doesn't exist, in which case loading it again will give you two *different* module objects in different scopes; or sys.modules["package.submodule"] will exist but "submodule" won't be an attribute of the parent package object (sys.modules["package"]), and "import package.submodule" will do nothing.  However, if it does nothing, the code using the import cannot access submodule as an attribute of package!

---

Theoretically, how importing a submodule works could be changed if the rest of the import machinery was changed to match.

If you just need to know what importing a submodule S from package P will do, then in a nutshell:

1. Ensure P is imported, or import it otherwise.  (This step recurses to handle "import A.B.C.D".)
2. Execute S.py to get a module object.  (Skipping details of .pyc files, etc.)
3. Store module object in sys.modules["P.S"].
4. `setattr(sys.modules["P"], "S", sys.modules["P.S"])`
5. If that import was of the form "import P.S", bind "P" in local scope.

Comment: And the scope of resolving unqualified names inside the \_\_init__.py of a package includes the attributes of the package object, right?

Comment: @yole: Yes, globals() in \_\_init\_\_.py is sys.modules["package"].\_\_dict\_\_.

Answer (score 0):

this is because `__init__.py` represent itself as package1 module object at runtime, so every .py file will be defined as an submodule. and rewrite `__all__` will not make any sense. you can make another file e.g example.py and fill it with the same code in `__init__.py` and it will raise `NameError`.

i think CPython runtime takes special algorithm when `__init__.py` looking for variables differ from other python files, may be like this:

```
looking for variable named "moduleB"
if not found:
   if __file__ == '__init__.py': #dont raise NameError, looking for file named moduleB.py
         if current dir contains file named "moduleB.py":
                      import moduleB
         else:
                    raise namerror
```

Comment: This is not quite as simple as that. If you do not import moduleB in \_\_init__.py, the name will not be resolved.

Comment: @yole yes, sorry. i forget restart python shell after modification